# Jenkins: addOrReplaceAction() throwing strange exception

Tags: java, jenkins

I was attempting to add parameters to a job with a Trigger plugin I'm writing. Here's the incriminating line of code:

```
job.addOrReplaceAction(new ParametersAction(new StringParameterValue("repoAction", "testan", "test")));
```

Maven compiles and builds the plugin perfectly fine. However, once the trigger is activated, an exception is thrown:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException   at
>   java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.removeAll(Collections.java:1068)
>     at hudson.model.Actionable.addOrReplaceAction(Actionable.java:206)
>     at *plugin package*.GitHubRepoTrigger.run(GitHubRepoTrigger.java:38)
>
> ...

I took a dive into the Jenkins Actionable class source code and noted that the `addOrReplaceAction()` function  uses a `List<Action>` collection which calls the collection method `removeAll()`. When I then looked through Java's documentation on this function it notes:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException if the removeAll method is not supported by this collection

By this point I was completely lost as to why this issue is occurring. Is something actually wrong with Jenkins? Or is my understanding of adding and modifying build parameters just dead wrong?

Comment: Typically, this happens because an Immutable List has been created somewhere in your creation chain. I would try manually creating a List<Action> and add the ParametersAction and see if that plays better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenkins wrote that function may cause unexpected results:

> concurrent calls to any of the mutation methods may produce
>   surprising results

See [java docs](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/model/Actionable.html).